# What happens if I install a software/application onto a dmg application/software installer?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-image

When installing Java I was given an option to install it onto a DMG file. What would happen if I had done that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you're using **Windows** or **Mac** OS as Operating system. DMG files are Mac OSX Disk Image files, same as disk image **ISO** files in Windows. The DMG files normally contain program installation files for Apple applications, but they can also be used to hold compressed files. If you're using Windows, then you won't be able to install the application, but you can extract and edit files containing it. For this you need **7-ZIP** and **DMG Extractor**.

When you install the Java Development Kit (JDK), the associated Java Runtime Environment (JRE) is installed at the same time. The JavaFX SDK and Runtime are also installed and integrated into the standard JDK directory structure.

Depending on your processor, the downloaded file has one of the following names:

**jdk-8uversion-macosx-amd64.dmg**

**jdk-8uversion-macosx-x64.dmg**

You have to download the file and then double click on **.dmg** file, then you will get the **.pkg** file. Double click on it and install.

Please refer to this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html).